# Velocity parse error on a null value

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, velocity

I have a problem in my velocity template.

I have to show the image url for some products.
I set a variable in a right way. In some cases anyway I don't have this image, so I have to hide the image and put a blank space in the template.

I write the set variable in this way:

```
#set ($variantUrl = ${#if(!$product.getOrderFormImage().getUrl()) $!product.getOrderFormImage().getUrl() #else $product.getOrderFormImage().getUrl() #end} )
```

but I obtain a parse error:

> Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException:
>   Encountered "(" at
>   de.hybris.platform.commons.renderer.impl.VelocityTemplateRe
>   nderer[line 403, column 103] Was expecting:
>        ...

I don't see any error in this line. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can nest `#if` `#else` within `#set` - at least there's no mention of it in the [Velocity user guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#variables).

When I use your original expression I get the following error:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "#if" at ....
Was expecting:
<IDENTIFIER> ...
```

If I rewrite to make the `#if` `#else` to be the top-level statement such as:

```
#if( !$product.getOrderFormImage().getUrl() )
    #set($variantUrl = $!product.getOrderFormImage().getUrl() )
#else
    #set($variantUrl = $product.getOrderFormImage().getUrl() )
#end
```

this seems to do what you want, or at least it compiles and doesn't error!  It's also a lot easier to read and understand.

Personally, I'd go one step further for the purpose of readability and use Velocity's [shorthand notation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#propertylookuprules) for references:

```
#if( !$product.orderFormImage.url )
    #set($variantUrl = $!product.orderFormImage.url )
#else
    #set($variantUrl = $product.orderFormImage.url )
#end
```